# How to execute some steps depending on the value of a macro variable in SAS?

Tags: sas, macros

In a macro, I set a variable to `Y` or `N` in a test.

The variable is correctly set.
Indeed, in the log, `%put flag_copia=&flg_copia.;` correctly displays

```
flag_copia=Y
```

but I can't test it in a `%IF` statement.

What am I doing wrong?

```
%macro carica(periodo0=);
    
    /* omissis... */
    
    CALL SYMPUT('flg_copia',"Y") ;
 
    %put flag_copia=&flg_copia.;

    %if &flg_copia.='Y' %then %do;
        data want_&periodo0.;
        set have;
        run;
    %end;

%mend;

%carica(periodo0=201602);
```

Comment: The value of `&flg_copia` is simply `Y`, not Y with quotes. For this reason, I usually wrap both sides in double-quotes. I would do:  `%if "&flg_copia."="Y" %then %do;`

Comment: @mjsqu It perfectly works, thanks! If you would like to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro variables in SAS appear as strings by default in comparison statements such as `%if`, there is no need to wrap them in quotes. As an aside, this is also why we sometimes need special functions such as `%EVAL` and `%SYSEVALF` to do things like mathematic operations in SAS Macro.

To compare a macro variable that is a string, it is either a case of omitting quotes altogether, or ensuring they appear on both sides of the operator using double-quotes (single quotes do not resolve macro variables).

The following code illustrates how comparison works in three cases:

```
%let flag_copia=Y;

%if &flag_copia.=Y %then %put NO QUOTES;
%if '&flag_copia.'='Y' %then %put SINGLE QUOTES;
%if "&flag_copia."="Y" %then %put DOUBLE QUOTES;
```

The log should contain:

```
NO QUOTES
DOUBLE QUOTES
```

The SINGLE QUOTES message was not output because literally `&flag_copia.` is not the same as `'Y'`

Generally to be safe, I tend to use the DOUBLE QUOTES option:

```
%if "&flg_copia."="Y"
```

Here `"&flg_copia."` resolves to `"Y"` which matches.

I think I use this because it is easier to test if a macro variable is empty:

```
%let EMPTY=;

%if &EMPTY.= %then %put NO QUOTES EMPTY;
%if "&EMPTY."="" %then %put DOUBLE QUOTES EMPTY;
```

While the first `%if` statement does work, it could be argued that it is less readable because of the missing right-hand-side of the comparison.

Comment: @CarLaTeX `%if 5+5=10` returns true because the %IF statement has an implied call to %EVAL.  This is also why `%if 10 < 2.0` returns true.  %EVAL doesn't know about decimals so it does a character comparison.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you! I was replying to something mjsqu was not able to test. If you look at the edit history of the post you'll see. I deleted my comments because no more necessary now.